# How do I convert a floating point number into erlang time format (and vice versa)?

Tags: erlang

I am trying to convert an erlang time format tuple, `{megasec,sec,microsec}`, into a floating point number and back again.

I can do this one way, e.g.:

```
{Megasec,Sec,Usec} = erlang:now().
Total = Megasec*1000000+Sec+Usec/1000000. 
1352802601.427
```

But I am struggling to convert this number back to the time format. I have a general idea to divide by 1000000 and round but I get rounding errors. e.g.

```
Mega = erlang:round(Total/1000000).
1353
```

If I could get this accurately I could apply similar steps to get `Seconds` and `Microseconds`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `erlang:trunc` instead of `erlang:round`.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Falco Hirschenberger's suggestion here's how I did it:

```
Mega = erlang:trunc(Total/1000000).
1352
Sec = erlang:trunc(Total - Mega*1000000).
802601
Usec = erlang:round((Total - Mega*1000000 - Sec)*1000000).
427000
```

Note. I had to use `erlang:round` to get `Usec` (else the answer would have been `427000.0457763672` - I think this is due to a rounding error introduced when I divided by 1000000)

Comment: Yes, the floating point representation is an approximation of the number with a constant relative precision, in simple word you have between  16 and 17 significant digits; not more. This mean that when you group all the information in a single float number, you are reducing the absolute precision on second by a factor of 1000000*1000000 (max, depending on the value of MegaSec). So when you want to restore MicroSec the approximation appears on the 8th digit.